# Can't understand why python ebay-sdk is giving error?

Tags: python, api, ebay-api

I have been trying to use the ebay shopping api and keep receiving the same error. At this point I am just trying the sample code listed on the ebay-sdk github page and it still isn't working:

```
from ebaysdk.shopping import Connection as Shopping
from ebaysdk.exception import ConnectionError

try:
    api = Shopping()
    response = api.execute('FindPopularItems', {'QueryKeywords': 'Python'})
    print(response.dict())
    print(response.reply)
except ConnectionError as e:
    print(e)
    print(e.response.dict())
```

It returns the following error no matter what call I try:

```
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found.
```

Any clarification on what I'm doing wrong would be wonderful considering I'm about to give up.  Here is the traceback if that helps:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Scott/Documents/Dropbox/python_code/get_ebay_item_info/get_ebay_item_info.py", line 7, in <module>
    response = api.execute('FindPopularItems', {'QueryKeywords': 'Python'})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ebaysdk-2.1.2-py2.7.egg\ebaysdk\connection.py", line 119, in execute
    self.execute_request()        
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\ebaysdk-2.1.2-py2.7.egg\ebaysdk\connection.py", line 184, in execute_request
    allow_redirects=True
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 370, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.7.0-py2.7.egg\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 946, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 986, in _send_request
    self.putheader(hdr, value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\httplib.py", line 924, in putheader
    str = '%s: %s' % (header, '\r\n\t'.join(values))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found
```